# How to setup a SQL Server so that Web api services function?

Tags: sql, angularjs, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have created an AngularJS project in Visual Studio 2015. It uses a scaffolded controller to receive data from SQL Server 2008 R2. Essentially, the request is made like this:

```
http:/localhost/api/Table1
```

When I run the project locally, by hitting F5, it connects just fine to the SQL Server database, returning the jQuery result as expected. It also runs when someone "outside" on my same network hits the page.

So I setup a Windows 2008 server with SQL Server 2008 R2. But nothing works. I must be missing something about setting it up. Localhost pulls a 500 error, so the trouble starts there, never mind external connections (they pull 500's too).

I have tried allowing outside connection (that was already enabled), various permissions, security settings, everything I could find.

Can someone point to step by step SQL Server setup instructions (from ground 0) that will allow this to work?

Someone must have gone through this pain before! TIA

Comment: Do you run your application in IIS on the server?

Comment: There isn't an "application" per se. The client makes requests to the SQl server with a JSON request as shown localhost/api/Table1. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Ok, but where do you host your api? The localhost/api must be running on something?

Comment: Maybe thats the problem - do i need to move something to the server? Note I have moved the project, maybe i need to do something else?

Comment: ok, so you have moved your project folder to the server? The next step is to connect your project to a web endpoint. The easiest way to do that is via IIS on windows server. Follow the steps here: https://technet.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/cc772350(v=ws.10).aspx